# Django filter adding results from two tables

Tags: python, django

I am trying to get results from two tables by filter. I want to get all the properties and if there is an agreement I also want to include the renters first and last name. Below is a simple model.

```
class Property(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=70,  blank=True, verbose_name="Property Name")

class Agreement(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="prop")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="First Name")
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Last Name")
```

Normally I get all the properties with

```
properties = Properties.objects.all()
```

Is there some way like below:

```
properties = Properties.objects.all()  \
   .somemethod(get values of firstname and lastname from aggreement if related record exists.)
```

I can loop at properties results and get the values from agreements. But I think this is not the preferred way as it will make many SQL calls.

Comment: you want to add or fetch? please clearly specify what you want it's hard to understand what you want to achieve. add example of what you desire after executing the code

Comment: I edited my question and added desired result. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: if you want to show it in django admin you may use tabular inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have changed the questions please use below query, If data available then only it will fetch the result, eager loading. Also if you only call `all()` then also it is optimized as that is Lazy Load and recommended by Django.

```
properties = Property.objects.all().prefetch_related('property')
```

Another option in your case is, RAW Query with LEFT OUTER JOIN, will more enough to manage performance.

Comment: select_related and prefetch_related will work the opposite way, such as: agreements = Agreement.objects.all().select_related('property')

Comment: Prefetch related is a Eager loading, as you try to avoid Lazy load of looping.

Comment: Use RAW Query with LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: I just understood your comment but you can have reverse relationship using `set`

Comment: Sorry for the first comment after checking it with prefetch I saw that it is working. But if  you put a related name you should use it in the prefetch.  properties = Property.objects.all().prefetch_related('property') works. After that I can get firstname of a record like this. properties[0].values_list('first_name')

Comment: I wonder if you can also answer how to refer properties[0].values_list('first_name') in template. Because I need to show it in html template. Thanks

Comment: Great! You found this working, I would recommend more that add your edit, and I'll approve that too.

Comment: Sure, actually you are using `[0]` because you are getting array of objects, if you use `Property.objects.get(pk=id).prefetch_related('property')` then you won't need to use [0] index, but if you don't know any ids there and if you want to display only first records then use `Property.objects.prefetch_related('property').first()`

Comment: Selecting the first record or any of them is not a problem. To make myself clear. assume that I loop in the template with {% for pp in properties %}. In view I can get the value with pp.values_list('firstname') How can I do it in template? That was my queston

Comment: `pp['first_name']` or `pp.property.first_name` could be the option not the `pp.values_list('first_name')` Not possible as that is not a query set.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more search with the help of "Anup Yadav"s answer. I found the way to do it. For easy understanding I also put a related_field definition for property field in agreement model for property.

So here is the way to do it.

```
properties = Properties.objects.all() \
   .values('name','prop__firstname','prop__lastname)
```

Now I can use it in html template like below:

```
{% for pp in properties %}
   Property Name: {{ pp.name }}<br>
   First Name: {{ pp.prop__first_name }}<br>
   Last Name: {{ pp.prop__first_name }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```